# Graph from file of edges

Tags: java, file, graph

I have a file that look likes this:

```
0,1
0,3
1,2 
1,3
2,3
```

Based on this file, I would like to generate graphs, i.e the function should take a file name and return a graph.

Expected output of `printGraph`(defined below) would look something like this:

```
0 -> 1 -> 3
1 -> 2 -> 3
2 -> 3
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
class Graph1

    ArrayList<Integer> [] adjacency_list;

    public void addEdge(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj,int u, int v) {
        if (!adj.containsKey(u)) adj.put(u, new HashSet());
        if (!adj.containsKey(v)) adj.put(v, new HashSet());
        
        adj.get(u).add(v);
        adj.get(v).add(u);
    
    }
```

```
class Graph2

public static void read(String filename) {

  AddEdge addEdge = new AddEdge();

  Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();
  
  File input = new File("filename");
  try {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(input); //read in the file

   while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] nums = reader.nextLine().split(", ");
    addEdge.addEdge(adj, Integer.parseInt(nums[0]), Integer.parseInt(nums[1]));
   }
   printGraph(adj);
   reader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }

static void printGraph(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj) {
  for (int u : adj.keySet()) {
   System.out.println("\nAdjacency list of vertex" + u);
   for (int v : adj.get(u)) {
    System.out.print(" -> " + v);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217574/discussion-on-question-by-john-doe-graph-from-file-of-edges).

Answer (score 0):

In this code block

```
public void addEdge(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj,int u, 
 int v) {
        adjacency_list[u].add(v); 
        adjacency_list[v].add(u);   
 }
```

You are not updating the map and putting information about the indices.
In printGraph method, you are iterating over the map which will be empty hence nothing will be printed.

Comment: Do you hae any thoughts on how to update the map correctly?